# Mail client sending duplicate replies

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, imap

I have my OS X Mail client setup with one GMail and one Outlook account. They both use IMAP.

I have an issue that every time I reply to a message I send two identical replies (from the same hotmail address to the same recipient). This only happens when I reply with my hotmail address, writing a new message works as it is supposed to.

Mail version 8.0 (1990.1) and OS X 10.10.

I saw a previous poster had a similar issue but the problem solved itself in his/her case. Anyone got advice on how to fix this?

Regards

Edit: Here is the mail setup
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you help us by showing/telling your settings in the email for the server to be used for hotmail under Mail Preferences Account. I have a smtp.live.com there for my hotmail.

Comment: Added to my post

Comment: Thank you :) just to test, if you use the online outlook mail (not Apple Mail) and reply does it work. Reply to a sender from gmail or outlook?

Comment: It works fine with GMail, both web client and Mail. Outlook web client (and local Mac version) works fine as well.

Comment: @Magnus did you solve the issue?

Comment: What is your outlook SMTP configuration?

Answer (score 4):

This problem happens only for Hotmail accounts in MacOS Mail app. I also had this problem once. 
While to setting up hotmail account in mail app try to add it as ***Exchange account*** instead of using "Add another account".
This process resolved my duplicate mails in sent folder issue for Hotmail account.

Comment: That completely solved the problem for me. I had the Hotmail account as IMAP, moved it to Exchange now. Everything works!

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely not sending each message twice, but saving two copies of it in your **Sent** folder.

Uncheck *Store sent messages on the server* under **Mailbox Behaviors**.

Your SMTP server automatically saves a copy of each outgoing message in your **Sent** folder. No need for **Mail** to duplicate that effort.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. I noticed this with Gmail a while back. Google’s SMTP server automatically saves outgoing messages to your Sent folder. Having **Mail** do the same will result in duplicates. I bet this behavior applies to Hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the only settings i found that might cause that is in the Outlook web client.

[image: outlook]

Try setting it to as shown in pic above.

I assume the IMAP sync is doing something it should not.

But you can try resenting the outgoing server for outlook in Mail app.

type

> smtp.live.com

Use this [Apple tool](https://www.apple.com/support/mail-settings-lookup/) to double check your email settings.

Comment: Sadly it did not work. I did also try tweaking the server settings and turning off saving sent messages on server as well. I will try to remove all mail accounts and add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Mail** -> **Preferences** -> **Viewing** and un-tick "Include related messages" in the **View conversations** section.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by usage of IMAP instead of Microsoft Exchange. It is a Microsoft email service after all.

Remove the account from the Mail application and add a new one via Mail -> Add account... -> Exchange.